# Miktex 2.9 installation error initexmf.exe

Tags: errors, miktex, installing

I have tried to install MikTex 2.9 in Windows 10 64bit (basic-miktex-2.9.7442-x64.exe)
It failed with an error:

*The operation can not be completed:
The executed process did not succeeded.
Details: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe", exit code="1"*

I have tried both: single user and all users installation. Under Administrator rights. From Downloads folder and directly from C. Does not work. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thank you
Lukasz

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe a problem with your firewall?

Comment: Are you using AVG antiVirus? They use an activity process that may/does block MikTeX tools from running and don't announce they're being blocked.